# How can I avoid the installation directory appears in the site URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

I installed Drupal 7 through the hosting service tools, which installed Drupal inside the *drupal1* folder. All the site URLs contain the folder name.

How can I avoid the URLs contain that folder name? For example, instead of http://example.org/drupal1/about-us, the page should be available as http://example.org/about-us.

I've been able to only set the default front page alias to the root.

Comment: Your domain needs to be pointed to the `/drupal1` folder. Normally there is an option somewhere in a hoster's settings panel. This is no specific Drupal question. So I'd say your hoster may answer this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Set server DocumentRoot to Drupal folder

As mentioned by @leymannx you have to configure your server virtual host to use the `drupal1` as the DocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /path/to/drupal1/

    <Directory /path/to/drupal1>
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

### RewriteBase on a shared host (in Drupal `.htaccess`)

If you're on a shared host you won't have access to change DocumentRoot. Instead, you can adjust RewriteBase in Drupal `.htaccess` file (or `$base_url` in `settings.php`).

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a  
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
RewriteBase /drupal1
```

Comment: Thanks @prkos I tried both the .htaccess and settings.php but no luck. I'll contact my web hosting company and have them make the change to the VirtualHost DocumentRoot.